# who knows algorithm about stones and backpack?

Tags: algorithm, prolog, bin-packing, np-hard

maybe somebody knows algorithm, or just what name it has, for putting stones (different weight) into different size backpacks?
I should do it in Prolog. I give weights of stones and capacities of backpacks. Program should give me an answer how can I place all these stones into backpacks.

Comment: I think in general this is often called a "knapsack" (or "backpack" to some) problem. There are algorithms for it. I don't know a specific implementation in Prolog, but Googling for "knapsack problem" should get you moving in the right direction...

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: He has multiple knapsacks, so it's actually a bin-packing problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell since you haven't given much detail, but this sounds like a [bin-packing problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem). You can start on Wikipedia and Google to find algorithms that fit your needs (note that this an NP-Hard problem).

Answer (score 2):

It's called the [knapsack](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem) problem.

Comment: He has multiple knapsacks, so it's actually a bin-packing problem.

Answer (score 1):

it's a classic problem, check [knapsack problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem)

Comment: He has multiple knapsacks, so it's actually a bin-packing problem.